# Secured Access database problem

Tags: ms-access

I have a problem to open secured access 2000 database. I have two files MDB and MDW. One week ago I could normaly open MDB using MDW file but now I can't. I'm getting such message when I try to login:

"You do not have the necessary permissions to use the 
object. Have your system administrator or the person who created this
object establish the appropriate permissions for you."

I'm openig the database with such command now:

{{Access path}}\MSAccess.exe {{mdb path}}\database.mdb \wrkgrp {{mdw path}}\workgroup.mdw

Where the paths for MDB and MDW are network share paths and there is still same problem.

Could anyone help me and let me know how can I open the database ?

Comment: Sounds like you're not actually using the same workgroup file as you were using when it was working. Or your shortcut has broken in a fashion that is not throwing an error. Check DBEngine.SystemDB to be sure your shortcut is working correctly. If so, then the workgroup is not the same one, or somebody changed the permissions on the MDB file.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it right.  Go back to whoever created the mdw and find out what he did.